# application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: Notification Center Key?

Tags: iphone, nsnotificationcenter

I'm working on an extension that allows the user to get some information from Safari using a URL Schema. I've used application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: before to get information from the URL, however I was trying to save the user the extra step of having to add this to their project and send the information to my extension.

I thought UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification might give me some insight but no such luck. Is there a different NotificationKey that can be used or do I need to have the developer implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the right notification, but your 
`application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method doesn't get called because it has to be on a real AppDelegate object.

Answer (score 0):

There's no documented notification, and in my testing I found no undocumented notification either.